# Fragment sometimes save variables while on back stack

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an ArrayList on an fragment that I populate from a server call, if I navigate to other fragment and check the collection size after come back to this fragment on some devices the list is empty and in some not.

What exactly is happens when the fragment go to the back stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acording to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle)

> Stopped
>
> The fragment is not visible. Either the host activity has been stopped or the fragment has been removed from the activity but added to the back stack. A stopped fragment is still alive (all state and member information is retained by the system). However, it is no longer visible to the user and will be killed if the activity is killed.

Once stopped, they are eligible to be destroyed.

Comment: So when I replace fragments they are stopped, what explain the list being empty on some devices (and some not)? They all run on 6.x

Comment: Yes, they are very similar to an activity lifecycle. Once stopped, they are eligible to be destroyed by the system.

Comment: So I have to always count as the items being destroyed, I'm still curious about why this happens so consistent on one device. If you have anything else to add feel free, I'm satisfied as an answer.

Comment: Usually this happens on less powerful devices (e.g. have less memory). In that case you can use onSaveInstanceState to save the state so it can later be reconstructed.